# Action on key-bind google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, key-bindings

Can someone explain me how can I bind a key likewise "ctrl+k" to a javascript piece of code to be ran linked to a google chrome extension? This should work on any webpage that is opened.

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation and sample extensions? http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html

Comment: Yes I did, but still I am confused because I don't understand how should I bind any kind of action to the click of the keybind. Am I supposed to write that in the background page? And how should I write that same function specifically to "ctrl+k"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your manifest, you specify:

```
"commands": {
  "my-command-name": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Ctrl+K",
    },
    "description": "My description"
  }
}
```

Then, in your background page you can do:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  if(command === "my-command-name") {
     // Do your stuff
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

One issue seems to be that the combination `Ctrl+K` won't be assigned by default by Chrome because it's normally used for another purpose. If you specify `Ctrl+K` as the default shortcut, the command will not have a shortcut assigned, and the user needs to assign one from the 'Keyboard shortcuts' link at the bottom of the `chrome://extensions` page.

If you use another combination, like `Ctrl+Shift+K` it will probably be automatically assigned by Chrome. You can always check the shorcuts assignations in the link mentioned, and programmatically using `chrome.commands.getAll`.

Also note that if you change the manifest and reload the extension, changes in the suggested shortcut key won't have any effect. You need to remove the extension and add it again for the suggested shorcut key to be considered.

Comment: hm are you sure about that if condition? it didn't work... That method is supposed to work in any page of the browser as long as the extension is activated right?

Comment: @user2510745 there was a typo in the if condition. I also added more info.

Comment: it FINALLY worked! Thank you very much, I'm really really appreciated! Apparently I really had to reload the whole extension, do you happen to know the technical reason for this? Ty in advance, again!